# Inserting the plus minus unicode symbol ± as a keyboard macro

Tags: unicode, keyboard-macros, characters, insert

I insert the plus minus symbol ± frequently enough that I want to bind it to a key.

From emacs -Q, I've tried this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") "±")
```

However, when I enter `C-c m`, the minibuffer displays `C-u 1-`, suggesting it's waiting for me to finish entering a sequence.

I can bind `C-c m` to other symbols:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") "⇔")
```

This works as expected: `C-c m` inserts the double-arrow `⇔`.

I've tried other keys as well, e.g.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") "±")
```

This gives the same result: emacs interprets it as `C-u 1-`.

Is there something special about the plus-minus glyph that makes Emacs intepret it as a prefix argument? Why can't I insert it as I would other characters?

I have solved the immediate problem by defining an abbrev to insert the plus-minus glyph, but I would like to know why the keybindings above don't work.

## Update:

Inserting the character via `(insert  )` *does* work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "±")))
```

Comment: Weird. Out of curiosity, try binding the key to a call to insert wrapped in a lambda.

Comment: done! That does work.

Comment: This looks like a bug, to me.

Comment: I agree with @Drew. And bugs can be reported with `M-x report-emacs-bug`. More information [is here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Reporting-bugs.html).

Comment: I submitted Emacs [bug #33829](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33829) for this. It might not be considered a bug. Probably has to do with what's allowed in the string value for a keyboard macro, and how such a string is interpreted as a macro.

Comment: `global-set-key` is documented to take a command definition as its second argument. A string is not a command definition.

Comment: Actually, forget I said that, it's not true. Something is wrong.

Comment: @rpluim I reverted to the original title. The issue appears to be with the use of the keyboard macro "±", rather than key binding. The use of the term keyboard macro was intentional, as in the context of a keybinding single quoted characters are treated as (short) macros.

Comment: I added an "answer" that covers the comments discussion. There is no bug - the keyboard-macro string just has a byte that can be rendered as that Unicode character. As part of a keyboard macro it is instead interpreted as a key sequence (command), rather than just a character insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to why you saw what you saw:

As Eli Zaretskii said in a reply to bug report [#33829](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33829), the string is interpreted as a keyboard macro, and Emacs *"interprets ±, which is a single byte with the 8th bit set, as a meta character"*.

It's interpreted as `M-1`, which is shown in the echo area as `C-u 1-`, as the beginning of a numeric prefix arg.

The mistake/gotcha is to expect that all bytes in a keyboard-macro string are interpreted as characters (which are just inserted).  This is a byte that is interpreted as a key bound to a command.  It just happens to be renderable also as a Unicode character, ±.

In the context of key-binding to a (keyboard-macro) string, as in the example -- especially since that is easily and commonly used to insert a Unicode character (or any char that is not so easy to type), it's easy to forget that keyboard-macro strings are command sequences.

Comment: Great, thanks. That makes sense. Avoiding the gotcha seems to depend on you knowing when extended ascii stops and unicode starts, or otherwise distinguishing between single and multi-byte characters. In my case, I pulled the symbols from `helm-unicode`, which doesn't indicate which symbols are multi-byte (nor would I have expected it to, before now). Fun fact: ± is a single byte, but ∓ is multibyte :)

Answer (score 4):

You can get what you want with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") [177])
```

or if you  prefer

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") [?±])
```

Another solution uses the package key-chord which allows you to assign commands to keys pressed simultaneously. After you have installed it, you can define

```
(key-chord-define-global "-=" [177])
```

and then pressing "-" and "=" at the same time does what you want.

Using vectors to represent unicode characters seems to be more reliable than keyboard macros. Emacs calls self-insert-command on the character C when it sees the key [C] where C is the character (the decimal repersentation) of the unicode character you want.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'm curious what the difference between a vector and the equivalent keyboard macro is. There are a few ascii codes that are used to represent modified numbers. ±²³´µ¶·¸¹° are used for M-1 through M-0, but this only effects keyboard macros, not vectors, as your solution demonstrates.

Comment: I think what is happening is that M- is still thought of as changing one bit (presumably adding 128) to the ascii code for 1,2 etc. So it is that  the keyboard macro "±" is interpreted as "M-1".

Comment: that looks right, and applies to other characters too - the symbol `î` is ascii 238, or 110 + 128. `n` is ascii 110, so trying to use the keyboard macro `"î"` fails too - presumably because Emacs uses that code to represent `M-n`.

Comment: Here's confirmation from Eli Z: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33829#11 I guess this is obvious to people who know which characters are single bytes and which are multibytes ;)